# Rename selected collections and objects

Tags: python

I would like to rename every collection and object I currently have selected.
[image]

Code:

```
import bpy

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
for x in selection:
    x.name = 'test_' + x.name
    x.data.name = 'test_' + x.data.name
```

But the variable `selection` does not have any collections in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only renames **active collection** and **selected objects:**

```
import bpy

def testFunction():
    selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
    for x in selection:
        x.name = 'test_' + x.name
        x.data.name = 'test_' + x.data.name
    collection = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
    if collection.name == 'Master Collection':
        return
    collection.name = 'test_' + collection.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testFunction()
```